Installing ScientoPy on Mac OS Sonoma
I am trying to install ScientoPy on mac. And I am new to this software. from my reading, there is no information on how to install ScientoPy on Mac. But if there is a way to do it, can someone help and guide me for installation process.

You can follow the debian just change the "apt-get" to "brew".
ref link : https://github.com/jpruiz84/ScientoPy
some command. However, if developer do not specific the MAcOS, it mean they never test their program on Mac.
you might follow this step

brew install python@3.7 (I am not clear about how to specific the version of python, you might know well then me for this step.)
brew install python-tk
others package than that, normally I install by pip.
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip Pillow unidecode numpy pandas scipy matplotlib wordcloud


If you download the latest ScientoPy distribution and unzip it you'll find that it contains a user manual (ScientoPyGui_user_manual.pdf)
The manual states that once you've unzipped the distribution you should run ScientoPyGui.exe. That is a Windows executable. That should give you clue as to this tool's limitations
